# Convert String into integer in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview in which I insert a checkbox on `check_changed` even I write the following codes to get the value of Issue Id as mentioned in image also showing values in textbox, but when I use these string in SQL:

```
Select * from IssueBook Where IssueId IN (values)
```

It shows error converting varchar to numeric on `check_changed` I write these codes I have take IssueId (numeric)

```
Protected Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim x As String = ""
        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("checkbox1")
            If cb IsNot Nothing AndAlso cb.Checked Then
                If x <> "" Then
                    x += ","
                End If
                x += row.Cells(1).Text
            End If
        Next
        RwId.Text = x
        Session("SelctdIsuedBokNo") = RwId.Text
```

In data table I used numeric value. 
How can I convert above codes into integers such as `4,5,6,` with comma separator?

Comment: What exactly does your code look like for the SQL query, and where exactly is the error occurring?  I don't think that's all of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IN statement requires a list of comma separated values, not a "string" with those values.

You should create a dynamic SQL and pass it to your Command (SqlCommand or whatever method you are using to execute SQL)... something like: (If you are using SqlClient)

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("Select * from IssueBook Where IssueId IN ({0})", values), your_connection);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about use `Convert.ToInt32();` function

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx

Comment: I don't think the problem is converting to an integer; the problem is that they're trying to use a comma-delimited list of numbers in an ad-hoc SQL query, and they haven't shown us the full code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an array :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx

and convert values into Integer with

`Integer.TryParse`

http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-vbnet

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Integer.Parse()
```

or

```
Integer.TryParse()
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert the string "4,5,6" into a single integer value.

Your best bet is to change the select to accept a varchar value.

Answer (score 0):

In this case to avoid sql injection and as long as your IDs (Cells(1).Text values) are integers you should collect your IDs from cells and type safe them in an integer list, then join them with a comma into a string at the end

I've adjusted your code accordingly.

```
Protected Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim Values As List(Of Integer)'your integer list of IDs 
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim cb As CheckBox = row.FindControl("checkbox1")
        If cb IsNot Nothing AndAlso cb.Checked Then
            Values.Add(Integer.convert(row.Cells(1).Text))'add the ID
        End If
    Next
    RwId.Text = String.Join(",", Values)'pull out the list into a comma delimited string eg "2,45,67,87"
    Session("SelctdIsuedBokNo") = RwId.Text
```

Comment: There are two following erros in above mentioned script kindly elaborate Error 1 'Convert' is a type and cannot be used as an expression. 
Error 2 Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String'.